# Error in syntax! (success is not a function)

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, syntax-error, response

I've been trying to solve the problem for two days. Every vs validator shows me a mistake on (((( 'success(function (response) {' ... )))), and on github example that is the right syntax.

Here is code..

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('braintree.token') }}'
    }).success(function (response) {
        braintree.setup(response.data.token, 'dropin', {
            container: 'dropin-container',
             onReady: function () {
                $('#payment-button').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Incorrect use of quotes `'{{ route('braintree.token') }}'`. Change any of the quote pair to double quote.

Comment: I did and nothing changes! Console tells that problem is in '}).success(function (response) {'  part...

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? the `.success` method has been deprecated since v3.0. From the docs: `The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.`

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> @ChiragRavindra

Comment: Try using `.done()` instead of  `.success()`

Comment: @ChiragRavindra I used .done() and it works. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

`.success` has been deprecated since jQuery v3.0

From the docs:

> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead

Try using `.done()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `.then()` instead of `.success()`.